# Cognos Analytics 11.x: How to "preview with no data" by default for all users

Tags: cognos

In Cognos Analytics 11, For query studio. How to force user to use the option "preview with no data" when building a query studio report. I basically want to user to build the query with no data then when he/she is done with building it to click run an click the data. I know each user can do it for him/her self but I want to in force it globally

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is the same for previous versions of Cognos. This is how I addressed my issue in 11 and it worked for me
1- On the server(s) where the dispatcher is installed, add an entry to `/cognos/analytics/templates/ps/qs/systemt.xml`

```
param name="limitedDataMode">nodata</param>
```

[image]

Then restart the system.